# How can I add hyperlinks to certain elements of the WTP XML editor?

Tags: xml, hyperlink, editor

I have to implement an editor for a certain language. This language uses XML-Files for the organisation of its various elements.

I would like to link from the XML-representation of the element to the real element in the respective file.

```
<ML name="ABC">
        <ConfigFilePath name="%mlpath%\mls\ml\abc.ml"/>
</ML>
```

So the element "ABC" should be a hyperlink. If I click it, it should open the path within eclipse with my own editor.

Do you have ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Contribute a hyperlink detector: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_hyperlinkDetectors.html